# priority in macro (++x vs x++ in macro)

Tags: c, macros, operator-precedence

I just wrote this code and got output that I didn't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SQUERE(X) ((X)*(X))

int main(void) {
    int s=5,i;
    i=SQUERE(s);      // option 1
    i=SQUERE(s++);    // option 2
    i=SQUERE(++s);    // option 3
    printf("%d %d",i,s);
    return 0;
}
```

The first option in the macro returned "25 5" - which I completely understand.

The second option returned "30 7" which I didn't understand - why is `s` 7 and not 6? and why 30 and not 25?(first `s*s` and then `s++`)

The third option returned "49 7" - and that I didn't get either.
I will be happy for explanation for the steps of the program until the output.

Comment: Short answer: *undefined behavior*. You must not modify a variable more than once in a single expression.

Comment: Because undefined behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor is just text manipulation, your code expands to:

```
i = (s) * (s);
```

or

```
i = (s++) * (s++);
```

or

```
i = (++s) * (++s);
```

And both of the last two are undefined behavior.